# AWS lambda event source mapping for SQS Queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have integrated SQS with Lambda and trying to tune it for minimum concurrency and maximum throughput.

Based on the AWS documentation there is event source mapping mechanism in AWS lambda for SQS. Event source mapper is a process which will poll the messages from the lambda queue and send batch of messages to our lambda function. So, we can configure **batchWindow** saying how long event source mapper poll for the messages before sending it to lambda function.

As per the docs, Lambda function may be invoked as soon as any of the below are true:

1. the batch size limit has been reached
2. the batching window has expired
3. the batch reaches the payload limit of 6 MB

I have a few doubts regarding event source mapper:

1. Does event source mapping process keep polling messages after sending batch to lambda function(async) or it starts only after it gets the response from the lambda function(synchronous)?
2. Is there any corner case where it will send the messages to lambda function even before it's batch window expires (other than size limit reached or payload limit exceeds 6 mb)
3. If event source mapper and lambda function has one to one mapping?

Please provide some feedback to the queries.